# Redux Selector not triggering when I'm calling it from mapstatetoprops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

Now I'm working in react-redux. I'm trying to get questions from state one-by-one. Generated unique ID to store the questions in the state, after user submits,answer also store with the question.

Uniqueid: { 
     Question: question goes here,
     Answer: ''
}

React component to render the question. I used selector in the mapstatetoprops to select question from state.

Now is my question:
  Selector triggers first time perfectly. After user submits the question answer also updated. After that, selector not triggering, I can't find why?

Comment: Hi zinc,. Is there by any chance reselector has the previous state?

Comment: Post your code - it will give those trying to help you something to work with.

Comment: Could you show your reducer code? It should return a full new state object every time

Answer (score 2):

I'm still seeing activity in this page. Redux selector can't recognize changes in the object of object or array of objects. See the below example.

```
{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"}
```

Selector can recognize the changes in the above object.

```
{
  firstName:"John", 
  lastName:"Doe", 
  featuer: { 
    age:50, 
    eyeColor:"blue" 
  }
}
```

If you made changes in the `featuer` object selectore won't recognize the changes. Same thing goes for the below array object too.

```
[
  {
    firstName:"John", 
    lastName:"Doe",
    age:50, 
    eyeColor:"blue"
  },
  {
    firstName:"John", 
    lastName:"Doe",
    age:50, 
    eyeColor:"blue"
  }
]
```

Comment: Tks a lot @satheesh this was our problem and we to know that object of object things made us realize the problem indeed.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how are you updating your redux store. please make sure you are doing it right using [redux troubleshooting](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Redux store updated perfectly, I can see that in the mapstatetoprops, which is before I'm calling the selector.